# unable to read values from env in AKS for Angular app

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, azure-aks, nginx-config

In our angular app we are using i18n. we wanted to deploy the application in kubernetes. now, since we want to build once and deploy to multiple env. for the configuration I followed this [link](https://pumpingco.de/blog/environment-variables-angular-docker/) . I have created env.js and env.template.js. whats happening is if I browse https://domain, its picking from the config at the root becauseI am keeping it in the assets folder. but once its loaded the application will be automatically route to https://domain/en/. from here the application is not picking from the config since it has its own asset folder in the path /en. I am thinking do I have have to replace the assets on the each locale or is there a way I can update nginx conf file that will help ? Here is the docker file.

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app
<Build Steps>

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
# remove default conf
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY --from=build /app/dist/<app>/ /usr/share/nginx/html
# doing this, because at the time of loading we dont have the assets 
COPY --from=build /app/dist/<app>/en/assets/ /usr/share/nginx/html/assets
RUN rm /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.js
EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/bin/sh",  "-c",  "envsubst < /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.template.js > /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.js && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to Fix it by introducing a executable file in the docker. here is the updated docker and sh files.

entry.sh

```
#!/bin/sh  This will changes based on the image, I am using alpine
set -eu
envsubst < /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.template.js > /usr/share/nginx/html/en/assets/env.js
envsubst < /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.template.js > /usr/share/nginx/html/es-US/assets/env.js
exec "$@"
```

Docker

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entry.sh"]
```